# Is it right we think whenever AWS gets a snapshot, it just copies the the storage layer of RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Based on the docs provided on the AWS site, is it right to think whenever AWS gets a snapshot from our RDS, it just copies the storage layer of our RDS? Because [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/backup-file.html), Postgresql said for getting a backup from the data of your database, It doesn't suggest getting a copy from the storage path your database stores its data. And for something Postgresql said on its site, we don't know getting a snapshot from our RDS is the right work or not?

The other thing that we aren't sure about is that the data in the snapshot is exactly like the data we have in our RDS when we get a snapshot from the RDS. Is that right we think both exactly have the same data?

We appreciate any comment to illuminate our question.

Comment: Thanks for asking, on the [Postgresql site](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/backup-file.html), it speaks about "consistent snapshot" as another way for getting backups from the database. I think because RDS uses EBS snapshot (as you said), and EBS has this ability to take "crash-consistent snapshot". Thus, we can just rely on that and it does not need to worry about the data of the database. Is that right? Or do I think wrong?@Marcin

Comment: Sure, your answer and your comments were very helpful to me. @Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> copies the storage layer of our RDS

Yes. This is just an [EBS snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html) which is adjusted to work with RDS.

> Is that right we think both exactly have the same data?

Yes. That's the entire point of snapshot - full backup.

Comment: Thank Marcin for answering, and what's your idea about the thing Postgresql said on its site (instead of getting a copy from the storage layer, it's better to run the "pg_dump" command for having a backup from the data of your database)?

Comment: @fresxckiuhnm `pg_dump` will allow you to restore your database outside of RDS, e.g. on local database, or different cloud provider. RDS snapshots or only useful for RDS.

Comment: In your view, here, the opinion of Postgresql isn't important? Because RDS without losing any data and just by getting a snapshot will provide a full backup from the data of RDS for us, is that right?

Comment: @fresxckiuhnm rds snapshots are generally enough. If the data is important you can also automatically copy snapshots to different region for disaster recovery.